# How i can use FetchedResults in coredata for populating an array?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have been able to implement MVVM in swiftui with coredata and the info shows up as i want, so all is well there , i attach the image of fetched data...

However one issue i am facing is i am unable to fetch the results from coredata and pass it to an array using FetchedResults, i am currently using the below code it works with demo data but not with FetchedResults , can any one kindly help with this as to how to populate an Array with the results of FetchedResults from coredata...because the data that flows in the MVVM will come from this repository itself ... thanks

```
    import Foundation
    import SwiftUI
    import CoreData
    import AVFoundation
    import Combine

class SongRepository: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
  @Published var song = [Song]()
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
   
  @FetchRequest(entity: Artists.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var artists1: FetchedResults<Artists>
            
 init() {
    loadData()      
  }
   
  func loadData(){
    //Does NOT WORK
//    song = artists1.map {
//      artist in
//      Song(album: artist.album, artistImage: artist.artistImage, artistname: artist.artistname!, genre: artist.genre, songMp3: artist.songMp3, songname: artist.songname)


    //Works with demo data like this
       song = [Song(album: "Raga Max", artistImage: nil, artistname: "Denny Jack", genre: "Classic", songMp3: nil, songname: "Love"),Song(album: "Rendition", artistImage: nil, artistname: "Ron Peterson", genre: "Western", songMp3: nil, songname: "Western Beats"),Song(album: "Ricardo", artistImage: nil, artistname: "Mahoba Rips", genre: "Folk", songMp3: nil, songname: "Rugged Paths")]
       
        }

     }
```

Comment: looks like the data is not ready in `init()`, try using `.onAppear { loadData() }`

Comment: @workingdog where can i use the opAppear in above code, it has no Views ?

Comment: good point, I did not realised it was not a view. Nevertheless,  in your view where you display the data, you should have 
access to a "SongRepository" instance, something like: `@ObservedObject var songRepo = SongRepository()`
then add `.onAppear { songRepo.loadData() }` to that view.

Comment: In this situation I think it is better to use a NSFetchRequest instead for more control. Actually I think (although I am not 100% sure) that @FetchRequest is a SwiftUI property wrapper that is only meant to be used in views.

Comment: I think you are correct, `@FetchRequest` is probably only allowed inside a view. So  as mentioned try `NSFetchRequest` instead.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - thanks you are right , i tried the below code and it worked 
 let context = PersistenceManager.shared.container.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Artists>
        fetchRequest = Artists.fetchRequest()
        let objects = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        song = objects.map {
                        artist in
                        Song(album: artist.album, artistImage: artist.artistImage, artistname: artist.artistname!, genre: artist.genre, songMp3: artist.songMp3, songname: artist.songname)
        
            }

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - you can post it as an answer and i will mark it as solution this will help many others ...